# Maximum nesting level of lists in Latex

Tags: latex

Is there a way to increase the maximum nesting level of lists (enumerate, etc) in Latex? I need five levels for a class, and Google isn't finding me anything...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LaTex, which belongs on the Tex subsite of SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to copy the definitions of `\enumerate` and `\itemize` from file `latex.ltx` and change the code from

```
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
```

to

```
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >4\@toodeep\else
```

and you will also need to define counters `enumv`, control sequence `\labelitemv`, and bunch of other stuff to support depth 5.

N.B. If you want to do this outside a .sty file, you'll need to surround your new definitions by

```
\makeatletter
....
\makeatother
```

In all it's a fair amount of detail work, but if you are accustomed to hacking LaTeX, it is fairly straightforward.  If the task seems too much, and you don't have time to learn, you could try posting a bounty here or elsewhere :-)

Answer (score 37):

## Solution using enumitem package

1. If you do not have the version 3 of the enumitem.sty installed, then [download enumitem.sty manually](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.sty) and place it into your project's folder.
2. For itemize lists, add the following to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,9]{label=$\bullet$}

\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
```

For the other list types this has to be adapted.

## Troubleshooting help

- if you get "! Undefined control sequence. \setlistdepth", the version of `enumitem.sty` that LaTeX uses is older then version 3.
- if you still get the "Too deeply nested" error, then the renewlist command is missing for the list type you use
- if you get "Package enumitem Error: Undefined label.", then the label for one of the levels was not definied with the `\setlist[itemize,$LEVEL] ...` command

Answer (score 15):

You can use the enumitem package. After what you just have to put the depth level you want:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\setlistdepth{9}
```

And you can have up to 9 nested levels for your lists, easy ;-)

This feature is available in the package since 3.0 (Ubuntu installed me the 2.2 for instance).  In case where you have an old version just replace it by:
http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.sty

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does not work for me. I copied the recent enumitem.sty and can call \setlistdepth{9} - but I get still the "Too deeply nested" error.

Comment: Found a solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 3):

You could also just use an `itemize-environment` within an `enumerate-environment`.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, the limitation is in the number of enumeration counters provided by default.  I've never had to do this but you might want to check the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Customizing_Lists) for some hints.  The last time that I had to serious tweak lists, I ended up falling back to using straight TeX macros based on some stuff in [TeX for the Impatient](ftp://tug.org/tex/impatient/book.pdf).

Comment: I don't think so --- Added a counter with \newcounter and a label with \newcommand{\labelenumv} and I still get "Too deeply nested." Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I did some more delving (in `ltlists.dtx`) and it looks like the limits are pretty much hard coded if you use the LaTeX provided lists.   `\list` limits you to six levels where `\enumerate` and `\itemize` limit you to four levels.

Comment: You could define your own list macro based off of `\list` and extend the limit or write your own environment from scratch.  It doesn't look like the standard LaTeX list environments are going to let you nest them much more deeply.